# Hamming distance and error detection/correction properties

Tags: hamming-distance

Let's assume I want to have a possibility of detecting 4-bit errors
and recovering 2-bit errors. What the Hamming distance should be then?

I wonder if it should be d = Max{2r+1, r+1} or d = s + r, where s is 4 and r is 2?

Thanks in advance for the reply!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
ed + ec <= dmin -1
ed = 4
ec = 2
```

therefore

```
dmin >= 4 + 2 + 1 = 7
```

and Hamming distance (t) is

```
t = 1/2(dmin - 1) = 3
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
d=Max(2*r+1,s+1)
```

is correct.

so the answer is 5.

When you have a minimum hamming distance of length 5 you can detect at max only 4 bit errors because if there is a 5 bit error then the codeword (obtained by having error) is a valid codeword because minimum hamming distance is 5 so insertion of 5 bit error causes conversion of valid codeword to another valid codeword.